# How to get by code the BatchJob Recid in job process?

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a custom class `extends` `RunbaseBatch`. In `run` method I want to get the `BatchJob RecId`. I try to use these code line:

```
this.batchInfo().parmBatch();
// or 
this.batchInfo().parmBatch().BatchJobId;
```

But in both case the methods retrieves a null value. Is there any way to get this information? Where can I take this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the static method `BatchHeader::getCurrentBatchHeader` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/batchheader.getcurrentbatchheader.aspx))

It returns an object of class `BatchHeader` with a property `parmBatchHeaderId` which should contain your desired information.